# Create Web service for my mvc application

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

I create a mvc application and i want to use some Push server and some web service for my application to communicate.

I found that a SignalR is best choise for Push Server.

Did I need create another web service for my other work or SignalR do the web services work?

If I need another web service, WCF is best choise? or I have another choise?

> Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need have to create a seperate web service for signalR. Please find the example below for signalR with MVC

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-and-mvc-4

Thanks
Naren

Comment: can you answer this question too : wcf is good choise? or i have another option ? or i am wrong what wcf is?

Comment: you dont need to use wcf, instead you need to use concept named 'HUB' in signalr for push notifications.